# Spark 2.0 Dataset vs DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

starting out with spark 2.0.1 I got some questions. I read a lot of documentation but so far could not find sufficient answers:

- What is the difference between

  - `df.select("foo")`
  - `df.select($"foo")`
- do I understand correctly that

  - `myDataSet.map(foo.someVal)` is typesafe and will not convert into `RDD` but stay in DataSet representation / no additional overhead (performance wise for 2.0.0)
- all the other commands e.g. select, .. are just syntactic sugar. They are not typesafe and a map could be used instead. How could I `df.select("foo")` type-safe without a map statement?

  - why should I use a UDF / UADF instead of a map (assuming map stays in the dataset representation)?

Comment: There is a project that aims to provide more type safety for Spark while staying on the efficient execution path: [typelevel/frameless](https://github.com/typelevel/frameless)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

1. Difference between `df.select("foo")`  and `df.select($"foo")` is signature. The former one takes at least one `String`, the later one zero or more `Columns`. There is no practical difference beyond that.
2. `myDataSet.map(foo.someVal)` type checks, but as any `Dataset` operation uses `RDD` of objects, and compared to `DataFrame` operations, there is a significant overhead. Let's take a look at a simple example:

   ```scala
   case class FooBar(foo: Int, bar: String)
   val ds = Seq(FooBar(1, "x")).toDS
   ds.map(_.foo).explain
   ```

   ```
   == Physical Plan ==
   *SerializeFromObject [input[0, int, true] AS value#123]
   +- *MapElements <function1>, obj#122: int
      +- *DeserializeToObject newInstance(class $line67.$read$$iw$$iw$FooBar), obj#121: $line67.$read$$iw$$iw$FooBar
         +- LocalTableScan [foo#117, bar#118]
   ```

   As you can see this execution plan requires access to all fields and has to `DeserializeToObject`.
3. No. In general other methods are not *syntactic sugar* and generate a significantly different execution plan. For example:

   ```scala
   ds.select($"foo").explain
   ```

   ```
   == Physical Plan ==
   LocalTableScan [foo#117]
   ```

   Compared to the plan shown before it can access column directly. It is not so much a limitation of the API but a result of a difference in the operational semantics.
4. > How could I df.select("foo") type-safe without a map statement?

   There is no such option. While typed columns allow you to transform statically `Dataset` into another statically typed `Dataset`:

   ```
   ds.select($"bar".as[Int])
   ```

   there are not type safe. There some other attempts to include type safe optimized operations, [like typed aggregations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39946210/6910411), but this experimental API.
5. > why should I use a UDF / UADF instead of a map

   It is completely up to you. Each distributed data structure in Spark provides its own advantages and disadvantages (see for example [Spark UDAF with ArrayType as bufferSchema performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47293454/6910411)).

Personally, I find statically typed `Dataset` to be the least useful:

- Don't provide the same range of optimizations as `Dataset[Row]` (although they share storage format and some execution plan optimizations it doesn't fully benefit from code generation or off-heap storage) nor access to all the analytical capabilities of the `DataFrame`.
- Typed transformations are black boxes, and effectively create analysis barrier for the optimizer. For example selections (filters) cannot be be pushed over typed transformation:

  ```
  ds.groupBy("foo").agg(sum($"bar") as "bar").as[FooBar].filter(x => true).where($"foo" === 1).explain
  ```

  ```
  == Physical Plan ==
  *Filter (foo#133 = 1)
  +- *Filter <function1>.apply
     +- *HashAggregate(keys=[foo#133], functions=[sum(cast(bar#134 as double))])
        +- Exchange hashpartitioning(foo#133, 200)
           +- *HashAggregate(keys=[foo#133], functions=[partial_sum(cast(bar#134 as double))])
              +- LocalTableScan [foo#133, bar#134]
  ```

  Compared to:

  ```
  ds.groupBy("foo").agg(sum($"bar") as "bar").as[FooBar].where($"foo" === 1).explain
  ```

  ```
  == Physical Plan ==
  *HashAggregate(keys=[foo#133], functions=[sum(cast(bar#134 as double))])
  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(foo#133, 200)
     +- *HashAggregate(keys=[foo#133], functions=[partial_sum(cast(bar#134 as double))])
        +- *Filter (foo#133 = 1)
           +- LocalTableScan [foo#133, bar#134]
  ```

  This impacts features like predicate pushdown or projection pushdown.
- There are not as flexible as `RDDs` with only a small subset of types supported natively.
- "Type safety" with `Encoders` is disputable when `Dataset` is converted using `as` method. Because data shape is not encoded using a signature, a compiler can only verify the existence of an `Encoder`.

Related questions:

- [Perform a typed join in Scala with Spark Datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40605167/6910411)
- [Spark 2.0 DataSets groupByKey and divide operation and type safety](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39946210/6910411)

Comment: thank you for this really helpful post. Do you think you can elaborate on the last point about type safety with encoders. Do you mean that the compiler can perform type checks on your operations based on the Encoder, but that there's no guarantee that the data you read (such as from a parquet file) actually matches this schema?

Comment: @allstar Pretty much. `as` should be more `as[U]: Try[Dataset[U]]` than `as[U]: Dataset[U]`. It is like `asInstanceOf`... But it is just a tip of the iceberg - it is really hard to stay within "checkable" path, with complex pipelines (joins, `Aggregators`...)

Answer (score 1):

Spark `Dataset` is way more powerful than Spark `Dataframe`. Small example - you can only create `Dataframe` of `Row`, `Tuple` or any primitive datatype but `Dataset` gives you power to create `Dataset` of any non-primitive type too. i.e. You can literally create `Dataset` of object type.

Ex:

```
case class Employee(id:Int,name:String)

Dataset[Employee]   // is valid
Dataframe[Employee] // is invalid
```

Comment: May I know the reason of down-voting my answer.  I  am sharing my practical experience.  Your answer is correct, it doesn't mean mine is incorrect.

Comment: I believe that someone already pointed this out in the past, but somehow the comment has been removed - this point you make here is not valid, as you compare different types of objects. 

`Dataset` is a type constructor. `DataFame` is a type, and to be more specific it is an alias  `Dataset[Row]`. What you should be really comparing is `Dataset[Row]` vs. `Dataset[U]`, where is not a subclass `Row`.

Answer (score 0):

DATAFRAME: DataFrame is an abstraction that allows a schema view of data.

case class Person(name: String, age: Int, address: String)

defined class Person

scala > val df = List ( Person ( “Sumanth”, 23, “BNG”)

[DATAFRAME VS DATASET](http://commandstech.com/dataframe-vs-dataset-definition-examples-in-spark/)

DATASET: Data Set is an extension to Dataframe API, the latest abstraction which tries to provide the best of both RDD and Dataframe.