# Why do Spark DataFrames not change their schema and what to do about it?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using Spark 2.1's Structured Streaming to read from a Kafka topic whose contents are binary avro-encoded.

Thus, after setting up the `DataFrame`:

```scala
val messages = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .options(kafkaConf)
  .option("subscribe", config.getString("kafka.topic"))
  .load()
```

If I print the schema of this `DataFrame` (`messages.printSchema()`), I get the following:

```
root
 |-- key: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)
```

This question should be orthogonal to the problem of avro-decoding, but let's assume I want to somehow convert the `value` content from the messages `DataFrame` into a `Dataset[BusinessObject]`, by a function `Array[Byte] => BusinessObject`. For example completeness, the function may just be (using avro4s):

```scala
case class BusinessObject(userId: String, eventId: String)

def fromAvro(bytes: Array[Byte]): BusinessObject =
    AvroInputStream.binary[BusinessObject](
        new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)
    ).iterator.next
```

Of course, [as miguno says in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40717852/488191) I cannot just apply the transformation with a `DataFrame.map()`, because I need to provide an implicit Encoder for such a `BusinessObject`.

That can be defined as:

```scala
implicit val myEncoder : Encoder[BusinessObject] = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[BusinessObject]
```

Now, perform the map:

```scala
val transformedMessages : Dataset[BusinessObjecŧ] = messages.map(row => fromAvro(row.getAs[Array[Byte]]("value")))
```

But if I query the new schema, I get the following:

```
root
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
```

And I think that does not make any sense, as the dataset should use the Product properties of the `BusinessObject` case-class and get the correct values.

I've seen some examples on Spark SQL using `.schema(StructType)` in the reader, but I cannot do that, not just because I'm using `readStream`, but because I actually have to transform the column before being able to operate in such fields.

I am hoping to tell the Spark SQL engine that the `transformedMessages` Dataset schema is a `StructField` with the case class' fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you get exactly what you ask for. As I [already explained today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483423/dataset-predicate-pushdow-after-asencoders-kryo/41483616#41483616) `Encoders.kryo` generates a `blob` with serialized object. Its internal structure is opaque for the SQL engine and cannot be accessed without deserializing the object. So effectively what your code does is taking one serialization format and replacing it with another.

Another problem you have is that you try to mix dynamically typed `DataFrame` (`Dataset[Row]`) with statically typed object. Excluding UDT API Spark SQL doesn't work like this. Either you use statically `Dataset` or `DataFrame` with object structure encoded using `struct` hierarchy.

Good news is simple product types like `BusinessObject` should work just fine without any need for clumsy `Encoders.kryo`. Just skip Kryo encoder definition and be sure to import implicit encoders:

```
import spark.implicits._
```

Comment: I have just resolved the issue, and this question does not *really* apply, because it was due to something not stated in the text. (My BusinessObject had a ``(`type`:String)`` literal identifier as a variable, which was probably the cause, since removing it allowed the spark runtime to pick the correct Encoder)

Comment: unfortunately, if your business object contains a LocalDate (which is not so uncommon), it seems like Sparks does not Encode it and you'll need to use Kryo...