# Spark 2 Dataset Null value exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Getting this null error in spark Dataset.filter

Input CSV:

```
name,age,stat
abc,22,m
xyz,,s
```

Working code:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Long, stat: String)

val peopleDS = spark.read.option("inferSchema","true")
  .option("header", "true").option("delimiter", ",")
  .csv("./people.csv").as[Person]
peopleDS.show()
peopleDS.createOrReplaceTempView("people")
spark.sql("select * from people where age > 30").show()
```

Failing code (*Adding following lines return error*):

```
val filteredDS = peopleDS.filter(_.age > 30)
filteredDS.show()
```

Returns null error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Null value appeared in non-nullable field:
- field (class: "scala.Long", name: "age")
- root class: "com.gcp.model.Person"
If the schema is inferred from a Scala tuple/case class, or a Java bean, please try to use scala.Option[_] or other nullable types (e.g. java.lang.Integer instead of int/scala.Int).
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Exception you get should explain everything but let's go step-by-step:

- When load data using `csv` data source all fields are marked as `nullable`:

  ```scala
  val path: String = ???

  val peopleDF = spark.read
    .option("inferSchema","true")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("delimiter", ",")
    .csv(path)

  peopleDF.printSchema
  ```

  ```
  root
  |-- name: string (nullable = true)
  |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
  |-- stat: string (nullable = true)
  ```
- Missing field is represented as SQL `NULL`

  ```scala
  peopleDF.where($"age".isNull).show
  ```

  ```
  +----+----+----+
  |name| age|stat|
  +----+----+----+
  | xyz|null|   s|
  +----+----+----+
  ```
- Next you convert `Dataset[Row]` to `Dataset[Person]` which uses `Long` to encode `age` field. `Long` in Scala cannot be `null`. Because input schema is `nullable`, output schema stays `nullable` despite of that:

  ```scala
  val peopleDS = peopleDF.as[Person]

  peopleDS.printSchema
  ```

  ```
  root
   |-- name: string (nullable = true)
   |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
   |-- stat: string (nullable = true)
  ```

  Note that it `as[T]` doesn't affect the schema at all.
- When you query `Dataset` using SQL (on registered table) or `DataFrame` API Spark won't deserialize the object. Since schema is still `nullable` we can execute:

  ```scala
  peopleDS.where($"age" > 30).show
  ```

  ```
  +----+---+----+
  |name|age|stat|
  +----+---+----+
  +----+---+----+
  ```

  without any issues. This is just a plain SQL logic and `NULL` is a valid value.
- When we use statically typed `Dataset` API:

  ```scala
  peopleDS.filter(_.age > 30)
  ```

  Spark has to deserialize the object. Because `Long` cannot be `null` (SQL `NULL`) it fails with exception you've seen.

  If it wasn't for that you'd get NPE.
- Correct statically typed representation of your data should use `Optional` types:

  ```scala
  case class Person(name: String, age: Option[Long], stat: String)
  ```

  with adjusted filter function:

  ```scala
  peopleDS.filter(_.age.map(_ > 30).getOrElse(false))
  ```

  ```
  +----+---+----+
  |name|age|stat|
  +----+---+----+
  +----+---+----+
  ```

  If you prefer you can use pattern matching:

  ```
  peopleDS.filter {
    case Some(age) => age > 30
    case _         => false     // or case None => false
  }
  ```

  Note that you don't have to (but it would be recommended anyway) to use optional types for `name` and `stat`. Because Scala `String` is just a Java `String` it can be `null`. Of course if you go with this approach you have to explicitly check if accessed values are `null` or not.

Related [Spark 2.0 Dataset vs DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40596638/6910411)