# Efficient way to read specific columns from parquet file in spark

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

What is the  most efficient way to read only a subset of columns in spark from a parquet file that has many columns? Is using `spark.read.format("parquet").load(<parquet>).select(...col1, col2)` the best way to do that? I would also prefer to use typesafe dataset with case classes to pre-define my schema but not sure.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```scala
val df = spark.read.parquet("fs://path/file.parquet").select(...)
```

This will only read the corresponding columns. Indeed, parquet is a columnar storage and it is exactly meant for this type of use case. Try running `df.explain` and spark will tell you that only the corresponding columns are read (it prints the execution plan). `explain` would also tell you what filters are pushed down to the physical plan of execution in case you also use a where condition. Finally use the following code to convert the dataframe (dataset of rows) to a dataset of your case class.

```scala
case class MyData...
val ds = df.as[MyData]
```

Comment: what is '...' ?

Comment: It means that it's up to you to define the case class that fits your data. For instance `case class MyData(col1: Int, col2: String)`

Comment: select(col1,col2,...) where col1 and col2 are strings representing the column names

Answer (score 9):

At least in some cases getting dataframe with all columns + selecting a subset won't work. E.g. the following will fail if parquet contains at least one field with type that is not supported by Spark:

```py
spark.read.format("parquet").load("<path_to_file>").select("col1", "col2")
```

One solution is to provide schema that contains only requested columns to `load`:

```py
spark.read.format("parquet").load("<path_to_file>",
                                   schema="col1 bigint, col2 float")
```

Using this you will be able to load a subset of Spark-supported parquet columns even if loading the full file is not possible. I'm using pyspark here, but would expect Scala version to have something similar.

Comment: Having the `"col1", "col2"` filled in instead of `...` made this a slightly more useful/practical answer than the currently accepted answer for me.

Answer (score 7):

Spark supports pushdowns with Parquet so

```
load(<parquet>).select(...col1, col2)
```

is fine.

> I would also prefer to use typesafe dataset with case classes to pre-define my schema but not sure.

This could be an issue, as it looks like some optimizations don't work in this context [Spark 2.0 Dataset vs DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40596638/8371915)

Comment: what is '...' ?

Answer (score 2):

Parquet is a columnar file format. It is exactly designed for these kind of use cases.

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("<PATH_TO_FILE>").select(...)
```

should do the job for you.

Comment: what is '...' ?

Comment: '...' is the column names to load.