# Spark proper use of Datasets?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, dataset, apache-spark-sql

**Background**

It is pretty easy to read about all of the benefits of Datasets in Spark including compile-time error checking, performance optimizations, etc.

When you start coding with Datasets though, you quickly find that many operations return a Data Frame instead of a Dataset.  For example, dataSet.select("a", "b") will return a Data Frame (at least in many cases it will).

**My Question**

You can easily change a Data Frame to a Dataset after the select by using a case class and .as[CaseClassName].  Doing this after every transformation seems a little painful though.

Is converting with "as" after every transformation the proper way to stick to using Datasets?  Or am I approaching this wrong in general?

Comment: For the record -  there are no _performance optimizations_ - `Dataset` of anything other than `Row` is typically much slower than `Dataset[Row]`. _Is converting with "as" after every transformation the proper way to stick to using Datasets?_ - no. The "correct" way is not using `DataFrame` methods. You either have dynamism, performance and expressiveness of `DataFrame`or somewhat compile-safe `Dataset`. You can't have your cake and eat it. Every time you call `as` things are no longer even remotely safe.

Comment: @user9613318 Can I have a source on that?  Dynamic typing is generally relatively slow.  Knowing explicit types lets you store things far more optimally and lets you do far more efficient calculations in general.  I also thought project Tungsten/etc were specifically coded to leverage the extra type data for performance optimizations.

Comment: Start with [Spark 2.0 Dataset vs DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40596638/9613318). Also Week 4 - Datasets lecture in [Big Data Analysis with Scala and Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40596638/9613318). Dynamism in DataFrame has very little to do with dynamic typing. What you really have there is a small compiler for SQL-like language. It is performance comes from a restricted semantics. Arbitrary `Dataset` is more expressive therefore doesn't  allow the same range of optimizations.

Comment: Cool, will check out the links.  Thanks for the follow up :).  By the way, I had the question because "Mastering Apache Spark 2.x" the textbook seems to imply a performance benefit, but I couldn't specifically determine what it was.  So maybe it's miss-leading.

Comment: The only performance benefit I am aware of is `Encoder` behavior. Generic `RowEncoder` is pretty slow, compared to  `ProductEncoders`.