# Reading Hive table from Spark as a Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to read a hive table in spark as a strongly typed `Dataset`, and I am noticing that the partitions are not being pruned as opposed to doing a Spark SQL on a dataframe from the same hive table.

```
case class States(state: String, country: String)
val hiveDS = spark.table("db1.states").as[States]
//no partition pruning
hiveDS.groupByKey(x=>x.country).count().filter(x=>x._1 == "US")
```

states is partitioned by country, so when I do a count on the above Dataset, the query scans all the partitions. However if I read it as such -

```
val hiveDF = spark.table("db1.states")
//correct partition pruning
hiveDF.groupByKey("country").count().filter(x=>x._1 == "US")
```

The partitions are pruned correctly. Can anyone explain why partition information is lost when you map a table to a case class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR** Lack of partition pruning in the first case is the expected behavior.

It happens because any operation on an object, unlike operations used with `DataFrame` DSL / SQL, is a black box, from the the optimizer perspective. To be able to optimize function like `x=> x._1 == "US"` or `x => x.country` Spark would have to apply complex and unreliable static analysis, and functionality like this is neither present nor (as far as I know) planned for the future.

The second case shouldn't compile (there is no `groupByKey` variant which takes strings), so it is not possible to tell, but in general it shouldn't prune either, unless you meant:

```
hiveDF.groupBy($"country").count().filter($"country" =!= "US")
```

See also my answer to to [Spark 2.0 Dataset vs DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40596638/6910411).

Comment: Thanks!, I expected as such, but could not find a correct documentation of this behavior. Thanks for confirming my assumptions