# Is spark able to read only column values satisfying some condition from parquet file?

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I have a code

```scala
val count = spark.read.parquet("data.parquet").select("foo").where("foo > 3").count
```

I'm interested if spark is able to push down filter somehow and read from parquet file only values satisfying `where` condition. Can we avoid full scan in this case?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50129411/why-is-predicate-pushdown-not-used-in-typed-dataset-api-vs-untyped-dataframe-ap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is yes, in this case, but not all cases.

You can try .explain and see for yourself.

This is an excellent reference document freely available on the Internet that I learnt a few things from in the past: https://db-blog.web.cern.ch/blog/luca-canali/2017-06-diving-spark-and-parquet-workloads-example

Comment: @thebluephantom..Thanks for sharing such a wonderful link. I am new to Parquet and it's helping me a lot

Comment: I wish if I could, I am not the owner of this question. hence just upvoted :-)

Comment: Yes indeed, it's well thought out and set out.