# Spark 2.x DataFrames or Datasets?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

My understanding that one of the **big** changes between Spark 1.x and 2.x was the migration *away* from `DataFrame`s to the adoption of newer/improved `Dataset` objects.

However in all the [Spark 2.x docs](https://spark.apache.org/examples.html) I see `DataFrames` being used, not `Datasets`.

So I ask: In Spark 2.x are we still using `DataFrames`, or have the Spark folks just not updated there 2.x docs to use the newer + recommended `Datasets`?

Comment: I see this question of being more confirmation of which to use and not so much about their differences.

Comment: [Spark 2.0 Dataset vs DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40596638/6910411)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Apparently you can use both but no one over at Spark has bothered updating the docs to show how to use `Datasets` so I'm guessing they really want us to just use `DataFrames` like we did in 1.x.

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrames` ARE `Dataset`s, just a special type of `Dataset`s, namely `Dataset[Row]`, meaning untyped `Datasets`.

But it's true that even with Spark 2.x, many Spark users still use `DataFrame`s, especially for fast prototyping (I'm one of them), because it's a very convenient API and many operations are (in my view) easier to do with `DataFrame`s than with `Dataset`s

Comment: Ahh ok, so Spark just hasn't updated their docs then?

Comment: No. `DataFrame` is a specific, highly optimized variant of `Dataset` providing additional set of features, over generic `Dataset`. It is not deprecated or obsolete, so there is no reason to update the docs.

Comment: Oh nice, OK are there any Spark docs/examples off the main site that show how to create or work with `Datasets`?

Comment: No? Weird. That's probably an enormous oversight.