# Disadvantages of Spark Dataset over DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark

I know the advantages of `Dataset` (type safety etc), but i can't find any documentation related **Spark Datasets Limitations**.

Are there any specific scenarios where Spark `Dataset` is **not recommended** and better to use `DataFrame`.

Currently all our data engineering flows are using Spark (Scala)`DataFrame`. 
We would like to make use of `Dataset`, for all our new flows. So knowing all the limitations/disadvantages of `Dataset` would help us.

**EDIT:** This is not similar to [Spark 2.0 Dataset vs DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596638/spark-2-0-dataset-vs-dataframe), which explains some operations on Dataframe/Dataset. or other questions, which most of them explains the differences between rdd, dataframe and dataset and how they evolved. This is targeted to know, **when NOT to use Datasets**

Comment: It is an odd question given that it is the way forward.

Comment: why so? There should be some scenarios where spark dataframes are best suited, we know that DataFrame is Dataset[Row]

Comment: in any event i did not do a minus 1. i am not a fan of row. eventually ds will prevail. it can use mapPartitions if i remember correctly. it blends rdd stuff as well.

Comment: [Spark 2.0 Dataset vs DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40596638/10465355)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark 2.0 Dataset vs DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40596638/spark-2-0-dataset-vs-dataframe)

Answer (score 13):

There are a few scenarios where I find that a Dataframe (or Dataset[Row]) is more useful than a typed dataset.

For example, when I'm consuming data without a fixed schema, like JSON files containing records of different types with different fields. Using a Dataframe I can easily "select" out the fields I need without needing to know the whole schema, or even use a runtime configuration to specify the fields I'll access.

Another consideration is that Spark can better optimize the built-in Spark SQL operations and aggregations than UDAFs and custom lambdas. So if you want to get the square root of a value in a column, that's a built-in function (`df.withColumn("rootX", sqrt("X"))`) in Spark SQL but doing it in a lambda (`ds.map(X => Math.sqrt(X))`) would be less efficient since Spark can't optimize your lambda function as effectively.

There are also many untyped Dataframe functions (like statistical functions) that are implemented for Dataframes but not typed Datasets, and you'll often find that even if you start out with a Dataset, by the time you've finished your aggregations you're left with a Dataframe because the functions work by creating new columns, modifying the schema of your dataset.

In general I don't think you should migrate from working Dataframe code to typed Datasets unless you have a good reason to. Many of the Dataset features are still flagged as "experimental" as of Spark 2.4.0, and as mentioned above not all Dataframe features have Dataset equivalents.

Comment: What about grouping by etc. Names are lost as well.

Comment: Is there any new insights on it in 2022? For me datasets are mature enough to be used as a safety net, certifying your inputs and outputs, but you should be using dataframe inside your functions for performance / readability reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Limitations of Spark Datasets:

1. Datasets [used to be less performant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40602882/1125159) (not sure if that's been fixed yet)
2. You need to define a new case class whenever you change the Dataset schema, which is cumbersome
3. Datasets don't offer as much type safety as you might expect.  We can pass the `reverse` function a date object and it'll return a garbage response rather than erroring out.

```scala
import java.sql.Date

case class Birth(hospitalName: String, birthDate: Date)

val birthsDS = Seq(
  Birth("westchester", Date.valueOf("2014-01-15"))
).toDS()
birthsDS.withColumn("meaningless", reverse($"birthDate")).show()
```

```
+------------+----------+-----------+
|hospitalName| birthDate|meaningless|
+------------+----------+-----------+
| westchester|2014-01-15| 51-10-4102|
+------------+----------+-----------+
```