# Why clustering seems doesn't work in spark cogroup function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two hive clustered tables t1 and t2

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `t1`(
   `t1_req_id` string,
    ...
PARTITIONED BY (`t1_stats_date` string)
CLUSTERED BY (t1_req_id) INTO 1000 BUCKETS

// t2 looks similar with same amount of buckets
```

the code looks like as following:

```
 val t1 = spark.table("t1").as[T1].rdd.map(v => (v.t1_req_id, v))
 val t2=  spark.table("t2").as[T2].rdd.map(v => (v.t2_req_id, v))

 val outRdd = t1.cogroup(t2)
      .flatMap { coGroupRes =>
        val key = coGroupRes._1
        val value: (Iterable[T1], Iterable[T2])= coGroupRes._2
        val t3List = // create a list with some logic on Iterable[T1] and Iterable[T2]
        t3List
 }
 outRdd.write....
```

I make sure that the both t1 and t2 table has same amount of partitions, and on spark-submit there are
`spark.sql.sources.bucketing.enabled=true` and `spark.sessionState.conf.bucketingEnabled=true` flags

But Spark DAG doesn't show any impact of clustering. It seems there is still data full shuffle 
What am I missing, any other configurations, tunings? How can it be assured that there is no full data shuffle?
My spark version is 2.3.1

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And it shouldn't show.

Any logical optimizations are limited to `DataFrame` API. Once you push data to black-box functional dataset API (see [Spark 2.0 Dataset vs DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40596638/10938362)) and later to RDD API, no more information is pushed back to the optimizer.

You could partially utilize bucketing by performing join first, getting something around these lines

```
spark.table("t1")
   .join(spark.table("t2"), $"t1.t1_req_id" === $"t2.t2_req_id", "outer")
   .groupBy($"t1.v.t1_req_id", $"t2.t2_req_id")
   .agg(...) // For example collect_set($"t1.v"), collect_set($"t2.v")
```

However, unlike cogroup, this will generate full Cartesian Products within groups, and might be not applicable in your case

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. The reason I moved to rdd is that I need to join 5 tables on the same key - different amounts of events in each table, and based on the events data create also some meta counters. It is a kind of conceptual map-reduce but i wanted to avoid the full shuffle by preparing clustered inputs.